# opengl es app stop drawing when show transparent storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I use xcode iOS game template, I create new storyboard viewcontroller for game menu purpose. When I present my transparent menu viewcontroller above game viewcontroller scene the game screen behind menu view stop drawing and show black color. 
My question is : How to display transparent menu view without the game scene affected and stop drawing ?

Comment: iOS game templates use either metal or OpenGL for rendering you game. So most probably it is not possible to render in view which is not the present view of the view controller. I guess there are 2 ways to achieve your need 1) Make the transparent view as  a subview of your game's view, then you just enable/disable you transparent view. 2) Else to avoid getting black colour pause your game rendering before presenting other view.

Comment: @GoodnezEverywer thank you for your reply. I have the transparent menu view but my problem now is the game view turn to black color when menu view finish the present transition! I want the game view to 'play' in background while the menu view is present.